# Can't release my appDelegate variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I juste figured out that I can't release the variables I set in my appDelegate from other class.

Example :
I have a class `myClass`.

```
    In myClass.m if I do :

    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.aString = [[NSString alloc] init]; //aString is declared and synthesized in appDelegate class.
    [appDelegate.aString stringWithString:@"test"];
    [appDelegate.aString release];

    NSLog(appDelegate.aString);
```

I get "test" in the console.

What did I do wrong ? : /

Comment: What do you mean when typing `[appDelegate.aString stringWithString:@"test"];`?

Comment: In fact I would like to access aString from other classes. Like a global variable. When I type this, I mean setting my appDelegate's aString variable.

Comment: Then you should write this: `appDelegate.aString = @"test";` or this: `[appDelegate setAString:@"test"];`

Comment: ok ! What if I work with dictionaries ? Should I write appDelegate.aDictionary = instanceDictionary ? (assuming I fill the instanceDictionary in a class and I want to access it from another).

Answer (score 1):

What are the attributes for the property `aString`? It's likely that you're using a `retain` property, which will (as the name suggests) retain the underlying object upon assignment. Therefore, after the assignment to `appDelegate.aString`, you've got an `NSString` with a retain count of at least 2. Your `NSLog` after `release` will thus be using an object with a retain count of at least 1.

Addendum: Your statement `[appDelegate.aString stringWithString:@"test"];` is vacuous. It's calling a class method on an instance (itself not a good idea), but this method returns a *new string* with the contents `test`. You're asking for this string, and instantly discarding it. `aString` is *not* altered by this method.

Comment: Yes my property is set as (nonatomic, retain). What property should I use then ?

Comment: It's not so much that you should change the property attributes (`retain` is fine). You just need to use it differently. To release the contents of a `retain` property element, set the property to `nil`. You'll still need to `release` the locally created `NSString` instance, as you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using properties correctly. Your code should read:

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.aString = [NSString stringWithString:@"test"]; // This will be retained by your appDelegate
appDelegate.aString = nil; // This will cause your appDelegate to release the variable

NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.aString); // don't put objects directly in to NSLog
```

As it stands you have created an autoreleased object (in stringWithString) and then retained it again by setting it to your property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "Analyse" system built into [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html). **shift ⌘ a - Build and Analyze.**

It will show you with nice blue arrows where you retain, release and overretain/overrelase variables.

Comment: Well I don't really understand how this work ><, but the arrows doesn't seem to go out of the method where I declare my variables, and I release it in another method. I looked closely to my code, and there is 1 alloc for 1 release... each time...

Comment: Read @jrturton's post, he explains this. Added to the Analyse feature, you should be back on track.